# How do I add more than one Create React App (CRA) build to a SharePoint page?

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, create-react-app

I made the shift from Vue over to React and I enjoy using the CRA tool to make interfaces on SharePoint. My normal methodology involves building the app and linking the build index.html file to a SharePoint Content Editor Web Part (CEWP).

I recently needed to have two CRA builds on the same page and I am running into the issue where control of the DOM by one build overwrites the content of the other build on the page.

It is now my understanding that multiple CRAs cannot exist on the same page. I do not want to eject my apps. In my research, it seems that webpack is assigning this["jsonpFunction...] to both apps. One suggestion I read involved finding and replacing all instances of this in one of the apps and changing it to "window.jsonpFunction...". I could not get that working either.

I want to continue using CRA and linking the index.html of the builds to different web parts on the same page.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Very Respectfully,

Answer (score 0):

I solved my SharePoint on-premise issue with multiple React builds working in separate web parts by doing the following.

1. In package.json ensure the "name" field is unique. Also, ensure you have a "homepage" variable set to the location you intend to copy the build index.html file.
2. In index.js set the document.getElementById to a unique name not used by other React projects that will exist on the same page.
3. In index.html make sure the name used for the root div is identical to the one used in step 2 above.
4. In the manifest.json, provide a short name and name for your App. This step doesn't seem mandatory but I did it for consistency in my projects.

Now you can build and copy to SharePoint. I use Content Editor web parts with each pointing to the applicable index.html file for the app. Works great!